# R code for unpaired t-test across multiple columns

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

I am looking to adjust the p-value (fdr method) in the following code:

```
>lstOut <- combn(unique(df1$ATTRIBUTE_Group), 2, FUN = function(x) {+ dat1 <- subset(df1, ATTRIBUTE_Group == x[1])+ dat2 <- subset(df1, ATTRIBUTE_Group == x[2])+ Map(function(x, y) tryCatch(t.test(x, y,var.equal=TRUE), error = function(e) NA), dat1[-1], dat2[-1])+ }, simplify = FALSE)
>names(lstOut) <- combn(as.character(unique(df1$ATTRIBUTE_Group)), 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
>out <- map_depth(lstOut, .depth = 2, tidy)
>out2 <- map_dfr(out, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'colname'), .id = 'classCompare')
```

Thanks so much,
L.

Comment: May be `out2 %>% group_by(colname) %>% mutate(padj = p.adjust(p.value, method = "BH"))`

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked. None of my p.values changed

Comment: It is creating a new column 'padj' i.e. `out3 <- out2 %>% group_by(colname) %>% mutate(padj = p.adjust(p.value, method = "BH")); out3$padj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `p.adjust`

```
library(dplyr)
out3 <- out2 %>%
              group_by(colname) %>%
              mutate(padj = p.adjust(p.value, method = "BH"))
```